# Determining the compatibility of Settings API & Multisite

Tags: multisite, settings-api

New to this forum so forgive any protocol infringements on my part and feel free to criticize so in the future I don't again.

Down to the nitty gritty. I'm working on a project and am very new to multisite and utilizing the Settings API. I decided the best way to learn was directly from the WP Codex. As I was reading the codex page on Settings API I discovered the following note.

"NOTE: *When using the Settings API, the form posts to wp-admin/options.php which provides fairly strict capabilities checking. Users will need 'manage_options' capability (and in MultiSite will have to be a Super Admin) to submit the form.*"

I've looked around the Internet but all the references I see seem to point to issues with building custom settings pages for the Network level. I am looking to build a custom template utilizing Settings API and replicate that for multiple organizations under one network. But each individual site would use its own settings, I am not looking for anything where it is changed once across all the sites. Example is each site would list its school name and upload that logo. Each individual admin for each site would be responsible for providing that information.

Would this be possible and what the codex is referring to. I also came across the following article on this forum. Again it seems to refer to Network portion of Wp-Admin.

[Settings API in Multisite - Missing update message](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/64968/settings-api-in-multisite-missing-update-message)

Comment: There are dozens of subtle and not so subtle issues when you try to use the Settings API in network pages. Just don’t use it at all.

Comment: I don't want to actually use it on the network specific pages of wp-admin. I want to use it just like you would use it for building any normal theme. Just regular theme options.

Comment: That should work. See [Settings API with arrays example](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/100023/73).