# What is the correct form action URL for network options pages?

Tags: multisite, options, plugin-options

Referring to [Settings API in Multisite - Missing update message](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/64968/settings-api-in-multisite-missing-update-message/72503#72503)

**It states that:**

> For network option pages the correct form action URL is:
>
> wp-admin/network/edit.php?action=your_option_name

Note: without a '/' in front

**Okay. Let's try it:**

`<form method="post" action="wp-admin/network/edit.php?action=your_option_page">`

**Obviously, my options form actually gets submitted to:**

> http://yourdomain.com/wp-admin/network/wp-admin/network/edit.php?action=your_option_page

**Now, adding a '/' in front:**

`<form method="post" action="/wp-admin/network/edit.php?action=your_option_page">`

**Submits the form (correctly) to:**

> http://yourdomain.com/wp-admin/network/edit.php?action=your_option_page

**That's right in most cases, I think?**

However, I got feedback from some of the users of my plugin, that they get this when submitting the options form:

> Not Found The requested URL /wp-admin/network/edit.php was not found on this server.

Is this due to incorrect server configuration for that user, or should I actually stick to the following form action URL to make it work with different server paths:

`<form method="post" action="edit.php?action=your_option_page">`

**Form still submits to correct URL:**

> http://yourdomain.com/wp-admin/network/edit.php?page=your_option_page

Would the latter form action URL work in all install paths that wordpress supports? (with subdomains, directory paths, etc.).
How about the different web servers: Apache, Nginx, IIS

yourdomain.com
yourdomain.com/wordpress/
subdomain.yourdomain.com
subdomain/yourdomain.com/wordpress/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When referring to urls within the network-admin, you should consider the 
[`network_admin_url()`.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/network_admin_url/) core function, that falls back to `admin_url()` for non-multisite setups.

So try this, using `add_query_arg` just as @toscho [uses](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/72503/26350) in the answer OP links to:

```
echo esc_url( 
    add_query_arg( 
       'action', 
       'your_option_name', 
       network_admin_url( 'edit.php' ) 
    ) 
);
```

instead of hard-coding it with possible wrong assumptions of the install path.

Here we escape the output for use in the HTML action attribute.